# about how translate gluon Desktop Programm

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-desktop

Aloha guy's,

1. can you explain the file for what this can be good??
   in project explorer -> Gradle: org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.12 -> Resource Bundel 'controlsfx' -> here the different file in different language. Can i with this translate my Programm content englisch,Germany,Polish and can i make it editable

   2.if the first one was a stupid idee how i can translate it?
   my idee is make translate properties lake this english.properties, germany.properties, polish.properties save in resources
   with loade with this

   ```
       stateManager.setPersistenceMode(StateManager.PersistenceMode.USER);
   ```

   try {
           input = new FileInputStream( stateManager.getProperty("Languge").orElse("").toString().trim()+".properties");// load a properties file
           prop.load(input);

   ```
       // get the property value and print it out
       System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
       System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
       System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (input != null) {
           try {
               input.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Desktop project with the Gluon plugin for your IDE, using for instance the Multi View Project template, you will notice that each view has a properties file.

This default properties file contains key-values in English. But you can easily create a copy of that file, rename it with a different locale, and using the same keys, provide values in that locale.

For instance, for `primary.properties`

```
label.text=Welcome
button.text=Go to Secondary View
```

you can create `primary_es.properties` in the same package, with:

```
label.text=Bienvenido
button.text=Ir a Vista Secundaria
```

Once you have several locales for a given properties file, your IDE will show all at once:

[image: netbeans locale]

And this is it, you don't need to change anything in your code. The default locale will be used to select the correct properties file.

Obviously, you can select a different locale in runtime. For that you will have to use a different resource bundle:

```
@Override
public void init() {
     // other Locale different than the default:
    resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
          "<your.views.package>.primary",
          Locale.ENGLISH);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@José Pereda

do you mine samthing like this for properties?
[image where i save Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEAEo.png)

I do also this in my WelcomeController

```
public void initialize() {
    String language;
    Locale currentLocale;
    language = new String("pl");
    currentLocale = new Locale(language);
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles/language",currentLocale);

    System.out.println(resourceBundle.getString( "greetings" ));
}
```

i do this

```
language = new String("pl");
```

because this

```
Locale.ENGLISH
```

dont have an Static `Locale.POLISH`

i also will be save for example (Germany or de|Polish or pl|English or en)  as an Setting

with this 
`stateManager.setPersistenceMode( StateManager.PersistenceMode.USER);
        stateManager.setProperty( "language", "de"  );`

or better as Programm Settings not in user C:\Users\Harry05.gluon-particle

Comment: Please don't add your comments as an answer. Just edit your question and post it there. Then remove this answer. As for your question, yes I meant something like the `language_XX.properties` files.